# C Binary Stream

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, raspberry-pi, ascii

I have got a raspberry pi bit banging at 1.25MBaud on the GPIO pins. The raspberry pi is to emulate an end system in a RS485 communications network. So hopefully that is the physical layer working :)

I am now struggling with the application layer. The c code libraries require Ascii for example "Hello, world!". It would be desirable for me to pass a binary stream ie "111010111010001010111", there will be 5814 bits :)  so I have been researching how to convert binary to ascii however only found complicated c++ answers. Does anyone have a simple solution? Thanks for your help!

Paul

Comment: "complicated c++ answers".... So which type answer is not complicated for you? (BTW, I am spotting some fundamental misunderstanding about binary, ascii and serial communication here. You really don't have to convert anything.)

Comment: I have to generate a binary stream and then convert it to ascii to then pass into a gpio pin library

Comment: Protip - it's binary, all the way down.

Comment: So what function are you going to pass it to?

Comment: gpioWaveAddSerial() in PIGPIO library

Comment: As suspected, it is taking array of bytes, not ascii-represented bits. The string you want to send is "Hello, world" as is.

Comment: In english: each character is1 byte == 8 bits.

Comment: @SerialMadMan, in principle, in C it is `CHAR_BITS`, which is implementation-specified.  In practice, `CHAR_BITS == 8` on pretty much every implementation you're likely to see today.

Comment: Moreover, when you send them via serial line, at least one start and one stop bits are appended. Optionally parity and some more stop bits can be appended. But it should be pretty transparent for you, unless you want to calculate some timings.

Comment: The library automatically adds start/stop bits, i want 9 data bits too which the function takes care of. i just have to pass it an ascii payload.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't need to break the string into bits the API does it for you....

Anyway if you did:

Each char in your "hello world\n" string is a byte when encoded in ASCII. ASCII actually only used the lowest 7 bits. If you want to pick apart a char into bits I would use the following code as a start.

```
char ch = 'h';
for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
   bool b = (ch & 1 == 1);
   ch >>= 1;
   // set the bit value b off to the pin....
   }
```

you would need a loop around this to process whole strings.

Comment: yeah not familiar with the APIs he is using. Still stands for a way to break chars into bits.

Comment: i am aware ascii is 7 bits. I am hoping to have 830 ascii characters representing 5814 bits.

Comment: 830 character but 5814 bits? How is that?

Comment: never trusting my windows calculator again!

Answer (score 0):

For move 7-bits ASCII-char to the port bit-by-bit, you can use:

```
void toPort(unsigned char x) {
  x |= 0200; // Set unused high-bit to 1
  for ( ; ; ) {
   char bit = x & 1;
   x >>= 1;
   if(x == 0) return;
   push_to_port(bit);
  } 
}
```